# Issue with javascript array variables

Tags: javascript, arrays, rhino

I am using javascript in my app which is a rhino javascript engine.  I like to use array for an array.

The following code is my actual working code.

```
    while (input.hasNext()) {
        var data = input.next();
        var new_data = {};
        var i = 0;
        while(i<data.get('total_entries')){
        new_data.entries = data.get('total_entries');
        new_data.id = data.get('out').get(i).get('id');
        output.write(new_data);
        i++;
        }
    }
```

I need to create array for new_data[].

```
    while (input.hasNext()) {
        var data = input.next();
        var new_data[] = {};
        var i = 0;
        while(i<data.get('total_entries')){
        new_data[i].entries = data.get('total_entries');
        new_data[i].id = data.get('out').get(i).get('id');
        output.write(new_data[i]);
        i++;
        }
    }
```

But its not working.  So, help me to create array variable in it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You mean something like this:

```
while (input.hasNext()) {
    var data = input.next();
    var new_data = [];
    var i = 0;
    while(i<data.get('total_entries')){
    new_data.push({entries: data.get('total_entries'), id: data.get('out').get(i).get('id')});
    output.write(new_data[i]);
    i++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var new_data[] = {};
```

First of all, that's invalid JavaScript.

```
new_data[i]
```

Looks like you want `new_data` to be an array of objects. Why not declare it as one and add objects on every iteration of the while loop:

```
var new_data = [];

while(...){
  new_data.push({
    entries: ...
    id: ...
  });
}
```